# How to update nested object of firebase data in (angularfire2 / Ionic), and also i want to update with given value not with key

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I was integrate firebase with ionic3 angularjs, adding data successfully like

```
  var fireData = 
           {
             userid      : '1122233',
             questionId  : '18022',
             answerId    : '25633',
             points      : '2'
          }

//Add

this.sample.list('paperCode').push(fireData);
```

Now I want to update like below mentioned image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the key, first query the data with the field you know then iterate through the result and get the key. Then you can perform update.

Try

```
updateFunction(questionId){
    this.sample.list('/paperCode', ref => ref.orderByChild('questionId').equalTo(questionId)).snapshotChanges()
    .subscribe(actions => {
        actions.forEach(action => {
          // here you get the key
          console.log(action.key);
          this.sample.list('/paperCode').update(action.key, { points: 10 });
        });
    });
}
```

I hope your question id is unique, otherwise it will override all queried results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a path to that object and update the field you would like. In this example...

```
firebase.database().ref(1710172911409/L5F4BEuePS8qxUqDNoF/questionId).update("NEWQUESTIONID);
```

If you don't know the unique id of the pushed object, you can query for it. Learn more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)